# Remove the overlapping feature in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1. I am looking for the removal of intersecting features. If any features intersect another feature then keep only one feature in the layer. In the following image, there are A-H features in a layer.  A & B and G & H are intersecting features. Among them, I need only one feature ( A or B and G or H) and all the remaining non-intersecting features.

[image]

Comment: It does not matter if it is A or B, just keep one?

Comment: This is an old and recurrent question. There are already some Q&A in GIS SE about this specific question. Otherwise, you can also check this: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/more-adventures-in-overlay-counting-overlapping-polygons-with-spaghetti-and-meatballs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the appropriate licensing you could try this workflow:

Create a topology with a rule of either Must Not Overlap or Must Not Overlap with.

Once the topology has been created, you could export the topology overlaps into a layer and then subtract the overlaps from the original layer.

Then you could return the exported layer, delete the identical according the shape field, and then append what remains to the layer in which you deleted the overlaps.